# What is applicationbase in UI5 developer guide?

Tags: sapui5

I'm following [UI5 developer guide](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/e62ef77a884d55930a7b818b8cf5f3/content.htm?frameset=/en/b2/f101ce998b401c8297cffffd6cfc62/frameset.htm), trying to build my first ui5 mobile application.
But when I trying to test my simple app, there's some errors raised:

> Uncaught Error: failed to load 'Application.js' from Application.js: Error: failed to load 'ApplicationBase.js' from ApplicationBase.js: 404 - Not Found

I went back to check my code. Yes, there's no ApplicationBase.js created. The developer guide only says to create application.js, but nothing about applicationbase.js. What's this file?
How should I implement it?

### I think the guide is not complete, I just can't start building my app by just following the guide.

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Edit code:**

Here's the bootstrap javascript tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Tell UI5 where to find application content
    sap.ui.localResources("util"); // paths starting with "util" will be resolved relative to the index.html location
    sap.ui.localResources("view");

    jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('ApplicationBase', 'ApplicationBase');
    jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('Application', 'Application');

    // Launch application 
    jQuery.sap.require("Application");
    var oApp = new Application({
        root: "content"
    });
</script>
```

And here's my application.js:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("Application");
jQuery.sap.require("ApplicationBase");


ApplicationBase.extend("Application", 
{ init : function() { // set global models
            var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/data.json"); 
            var imgModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/img.json"); 
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(model); 
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(imgModel, "img"); 
        }, 
main : function() { 
            // create app view and put to html root element 
            var root = this.getRoot(); 
            sap.ui.jsview("app", "view.App").placeAt(root); 
        }
});
```

I don't have applicationbase.js. The developer guide doesn't mention anything about this file.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see whats going on?

Comment: Just find and replace all Application to MyApplication and find and replace all ApplicationBase to Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issues and solved it after I found [this](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/ApplicationJs.html) in a different tutorial:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("Application");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.app.Application");

sap.ui.app.Application.extend("Application", {

    init : function() {
            // Do init stuff
    },

    main : function() {

         // create app view and put to html root element 
        var root = this.getRoot(); 
        sap.ui.jsview("app", "view.App").placeAt(root); 

    }
});
```

I think what they mean with **ApplicationBase** in the documentation is more like an abstract application (constructor) that you've created before. If you don´t have your own Application that you want to extend you can just extend **sap.ui.app.Application**.

Maybe this helps you too. Let me know if you have some more problems with that.

A whole overview and even more can be found [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/BestPractice.html).

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I also realized this and had figured out how to proceed. Bad documentation.